# Save HTML tables locally in the Angular/Django

Tags: html, django, angular, web-applications

I'm new in full-stack development and it's a lot of try and error. Now I'm struggling with HTML tables. For explanation:

I am building a simple web app that can show tables from Azure SQL Database. I am able to input the tables through a backend connection (Django) to the Frontend(Angular) for representation. but, every time I reload the app, all data from the table are gone and it starts calling the tables again. it would be great to save these tables permanently because the tables are so large and it takes a long time to fetch them again.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Hello @jasinAmini you can store the data locally using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if I can save them in Kubernetes.